# How do I extract only the value of all elements in a list of 'Around' as a new list?

Tags: list-manipulation, around

Lets say I have a list of Around values:

`A = Table[i RandomReal[], {i, 1, 10}]`

`Aerr = 0.1 A`

`aroundA = Around @@@ (Transpose[{A, Aerr}])`

and I want to extract only the list A from the list aroundA, how do I do that? 'aroundA["Value"]' doesn't work...

Comment: does `First /@ aroundA` work? if so but you're not sure why, it might help to view `aroundA // FullForm`!

Comment: in general, though, `expr /. Around[x_, _] :> x` will be a more robust way of converting all `Around` values in a given expression to their "centers".

Comment: It does thank you!! I feel stupid, could have thought of it myself!

Comment: haha, no problem, I know that feeling well! It's normal...and inevitable! :)

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) and the `"Value"` property of [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html).

With `aroundA` as in OP

```
Through[aroundA@"Value"]
```

> ```
> {0.530694, 1.15084, 0.510409, 1.87093, 0.977942, 4.65551, 4.93632, 6.49779, 8.71555, 8.52609}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = Table[i RandomReal[], {i, 1, 10}]
```

gives

> `{0.837063, 1.10488, 2.01849, 0.723948, 1.33068, 2.0528, 5.66006, \ 7.70551, 7.71597, 3.96396}`

```
Aerr = 0.1 A
```

gives

> `{0.0837063, 0.110488, 0.201849, 0.0723948, 0.133068, 0.20528, \ 0.566006, 0.770551, 0.771597, 0.396396}`

We run

```
aroundA = Around @@@ (Transpose[{A, Aerr}])
```

to get

> `{Around[0.8370625077162377, 0.08370625077162377], Around[ 1.1048780919842183`, 0.11048780919842183`], Around[ 2.0184867747510724`, 0.20184867747510726`], Around[ 0.7239475005839262, 0.07239475005839262], Around[ 1.3306838054523962`, 0.13306838054523962`], Around[ 2.0527967474000004`, 0.20527967474000006`], Around[ 5.660063341757798, 0.5660063341757798], Around[ 7.705509066450826, 0.7705509066450826], Around[ 7.715971740606534, 0.7715971740606534], Around[ 3.9639634962189185`, 0.39639634962189185`]}`

We extract the list you wanted like so:

```
test = Table[aroundA[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

We check what we did

```
test - A
```

> `{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}`